# I need to make this code work, but cannot figure out what is wrong. It is a System.out.format() issue

Tags: java, system.out

I cannot seem to get this code to format.  I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread 
    "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method format(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable 
    for the arguments (String, int, double) at 
    org.lineware.learningjava.Root2.main(Root2.java:9)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Root2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 2;
        double r =  Math.sqrt(i);
        System.out.format("The square root of %d is %f.%n", i, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: What Java version are you on?

Comment: You seem to have a versioning issue. Are you writing the code in an IDE?

Comment: I solved the problem,  but it was thanks to you for making me double check myself.  If you would answer this.  I would give you credit.  I simply went to properties>java compiler and changed the jdk compliance to 1.7.  It was at 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable arguments (varargs) were added in Java 5. Before that the `format(..)` method you were trying to use was declared as

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object[] args) {
```

In other words, it expected an array of objects. Since Java 5, the method is declared as

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object... args) {
```

using the [varargs syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). You're probably using a compiler version lower than Java 5.

Comment: Excellent,  it irritates me when I get a ide error.  I was all.  I know this is right.

Comment: @user3456442 Yeah, you'd think they would default to the most recent version. In any case, now that you know, you should be able to set it as the default for any future projects.

Comment: I just recently changed my workspace so I could use the github for windows.  I guess it changed all my settings as well.